# Need Suggestion - Angular 4 with IndexedDB

Tags: database-design, architecture, logic, backend, indexeddb

Need suggestion! Developing an application with Offline Storage using IndexedDB with Angular 4 for a hybrid mobile application. While I have already implemented CRUD operations and even integrated my REST APIs. I am stuck in my further approach.
Now, here is my problem statement.
1) I have for example 2000 records coming from my ReST service, and I will be storing it in my IndexedDb of the app (browser). I will display and edit the records on my page from the local DB(Indexed) and save after the editing in the local DB itself i.e. All my transaction is done with the local Indexed Db. How can I manage about the synchronization of the records between the local DB and the main DB which my application hits?
2) If any of those 2000 records are updated,  Do I need to sync the whole master DB to the local DB? Or how can I know which are the particular records updated? OK, having a flag can solve the problem for a while. But, there are two-way syncs to be made. a) The edited records in the indexed DB are to be synced to the master DB (I can't sync my whole Indexed DB to the main DB, I can just have flags and only sync the edited records to the main DB). b) The master DB may also get updated (any one of those 2000 records or there are more records added in meantime) I need to sync the master DB with the Indexed DB in local.

How can I achieve this? - I need to know the approach for Synchronisation and even updating the particular flagged records. Even any of the field in the record is updated - How can I adjust the flag?

I just need to know the approach for this, apart from the development of the code. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The user of the application can even perform the operations on the website, I need to synchronize with both.

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to know the approach for this, apart from the development of the code. Thanks in Advance!

The approach you could use will depend upon the technology choices you have. For example, you could use a database that built with a master/master setup that can run in the browser, such as [Pouch DB](https://pouchdb.com/). PouchDB is built for this scenario.

Another approach is to use immutability pattern where you don't edit any records just insert with versions. With immutability, you can upload your data to the server and download data from the serve based on your strategy, i.e when the client is online etc.
in your code you only need to work with the most recent dataset.

You can also use the git approach, where you have changesets, conflicts and merges.

Or may be you can use websockets to do the syncing.

Comment: Hi, Limitations - I am using IndexedDb for mobile - using Angular 4.